# C# Visual Studio 2010 form application error message

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I keep getting this error when starting a new form project in Visual Studio C# 2010. I think I may have renamed a file from within the properties manager, but not sure!

> The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the
>   classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the
>   following classes in the file: Form1 --- The base class
>   'System.Object' cannot be designed.

How can I solve this problem?

Warnings also include:

> Warning 1   The designer could not be shown for this file because none
>   of the classes within it can be designed.  The designer inspected the
>   following classes in the file:
>
> Form1 --- The base class 'System.Object' cannot be designed.        0   0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the properties from .net 4.0 client profile to the .net 4.0 profile.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the designer file. Right-click on the aspx file and choose *Convert to Web Application*. That should recreate your designer file properly and allow you to open the page again.

Comment: thanks for this! Where is the designer file and the aspx file located (i'm new to VS & C#)

Comment: @ForgiveMeI'mAN00b - although useful, I don't know if it is the right answer since I don't know where the aspx or designer file is...maybe you could point this out for me if you know? thanks

Comment: @gray Um, i dont really see sharp all that well but it should be somewhere in the folder that contains your project or the solution explorer